# Почему текст в C# после создания не изменяеться?

Tags: c#, строки, websocket

Я пытаюсь создать скрипт для передачи строк через WebSocket. После того, как я подключаюсь, я не могу записать полученную информацию в раннее созданную строку. Как я понял проблемы в самом C#, но возможно ли перезаписать строку после её создания?

Саму строку я создаю как все и привыкли: `public string Tex;`

А вот код, который и пытаеться перезаписать строку:

```
Ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => {Tex = e.Data;};
Console.WriteLine(Tex);
if(Tex != "") {
    // остальной код который здесь не нужен.
}
```

Comment: что конкретно, по-твоему, не так, с приведенным кодом?

Comment: я просто не понимаю, почему я не могу изменить строку, которую я создал в начале скрипта.

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что не можешь изменить?

Comment: я создал даже отдельный скрипт где создал строку как я указал выше и создал метод, который пытаеться изменить строку и на выходе я получаю вместо измененной строки ту же самую

Comment: Ты неправильно проверяешь.

Comment: ну если ты думаешь что я неправильно проверяю, то напиши пример кода, от которого ты отталкивался.

Comment: Смотрите, вы заявляете, что тут некая "проблемы в самом C#", то есть баг или фича языка. Ок, вот я беру, делаю публичную переменную, в методе задаю ей значение, вывожу на экран, задаю ей другое значение, и также вывожу. Получаем в итоге [такой](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ASGGt9) простой код. Как видите, тут нету "проблем c#", все отрабатывает, переменная меняется, выводит всегда то, что задали. Исходя из этого, ваша проблема не в языке, а в вашем коде. Допустим самое простое, вы ставили точку остановки на `Tex = e.Data;` - вызывается? А `Tex` кто-либо еще не меняет? Может он из другого класса?

Comment: Или может вы ожидаете, что `Ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => {Tex = e.Data;};` выполнится **до** кода ниже (`Console.WriteLine(Tex); ...`)? Если да, то это не так. Вы подписываетесь на событие, которое выполнится только в момент определенного действия (в вашем случае при получении сообщения от соккета). Вот когда вы получите сообщение, тогда у вас переменная и поменяется. `Ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => {Tex = e.Data;};` - это не ожидание, а лишь подписывание, не более. Короче, думаю поняли, что проблема не в C# как вы говорите, а в вашем коде, и мы со своей стороны не может это воспроизвести.

Comment: @Grundy не согласен с закрытием, показанного кода достаточно, чтобы выдать конкретный ответ.

Comment: @aepot, недостаточно.